# How can I get a value in a nested object quickly? The object is uncertain

Tags: javascript

I get a data from backend, the data is JSON format and nested，like

```
[{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 'value',
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
},....]
```

or maybe

```
[{
  a: {
    b: {
      // no  key 'c'
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
},....]
```

may also be

```
[{
  a: {
    // no key 'b'
    ...
  }
},....]
```

I have to  get 'a.b.c' safely, is there any good way to do it?

'a.b.c.d'?

Comment: Try `(a.b || {}).c`

Comment: You can use `hasOwnProperty` in order to check if property exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasOwnProperty()` like this

```
if(a.hasOwnProperty('b')){
   console.log(a.b);
}
```

Read about it here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty